# Fetch a column into the result set which is not in the table

Tags: java, oracle

My Title might not be clear enough. So let me explain the problem . I have to retrieve the values from the database store it in an array list and display it in a jsp page dynamically. for that am using a query

```
select customer, 
       id, 
       0 message 
  from TableName
```

My Table Structure:

```
customer  varchar2(20)
id        Number
```

I don't know how to add the column `0 message` into the result set since this column is not present in that table.

For example, if we give

```
select 0 message 
  from TableName;
```

The output of the above query will be

```
message
0
```

So now my question is how to add this column(message) into my Resultset and Array list?

Comment: I dont see a need to add these to the `Resultset` instead after populating the `Arraylist` from your `Resultset`, just add the `0 message` into it.

Comment: I have to do some calculation(addition) with this value (value obtained   from this message column) and it will change accordingly.

Comment: no. I want to do some calculation based on the value obtained from this column

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just wondering if you are facing any issue with executing the SQL query with the additional (non-existing in DB) column through JDBC.

for eg: - you can execute the below query directly in the database through JDBC

```
select customer, 
   id, 
   0 "message"
from TableName
```

Sample Code snippet.

```
Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(".....", "...","..");
ps = conn.prepareStatement("select customer, id, 0 \"message\" from your_table");
ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();
while(rs.next()){
    System.out.printf("%s %s %s", rs.getString("id"), rs.getString("customer"), rs.getString("message"));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

When you add it to your SQL-query as in your question it should also appear in the resultset...

Comment: how to add that into my resultset? If I add this into my resultset, It will throw SQL Exception since this column is not present in the table

Comment: Please show your code, if it's in the statement it should be in the resulset!?!?

Answer (score 0):

Hlo.. below code will help you..

```
package com.smk.jdbc.ps;

import java.util.ArrayList;


public class PreparedStatement {

public static void main(String[] args) {
try{
Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver");

java.sql.Connection conn = null;
java.sql.PreparedStatement ps = null;
String strQry = "select 1 message  from dual where 1 = ?";

conn = java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:wzdev", "user","pwd");
ps = conn.prepareStatement(strQry);
ps.setInt(1, 1);

java.sql.ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();

while(rs.next()){
java.util.ArrayList<java.sql.ResultSet>  ars = new ArrayList<java.sql.ResultSet>();
ars.add(rs);    

System.out.println(ars.get(0).getInt("message"));
}



}catch(ClassNotFoundException e){
e.printStackTrace();
}catch(Exception e){
e.printStackTrace();
}
}

}
```

Comment: Thanks Karthikeyan. let me try and get back here if the problem persists

Comment: can you explain this query "select 1 message  from dual where 1 = ?"

Comment: the query is nothing man. just i am selecting 1 from dual and giving column name as message.. u can use query "select 1 message  from dual" where you have to remove java code "ps.setInt(1, 1);"

Answer (score 0):

This code is working fine for sql server.And doing same for whatever u want.

```
public class ConnectionPool
{
public static void main(String[] args)
{
try
{
Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");
Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("","","");
Statement s = conn.createStatement();
ResultSet rs = s.executeQuery("select sRowId,  0 messa  from tblAccount");
while(rs.next())
{
list.add(rs.getInt("messa"));
}
System.out.println(list.size());
}
catch (Exception e)
{
e.printStackTrace();
}
}
}
```